# How to make association null in one to many relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to make one of the student association null with college but nothing is happening on flush/commit. I am not sure what's the issue . Here are  my college and student entity

```
public class College {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int collegeId;
    private String collegeName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="college", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Student> students;

    public String getCollegeName() {
        return collegeName;
    }
    public void setCollegeName(String collegeName) {
        this.collegeName = collegeName;
    }
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
    public int getCollegeId() {
        return collegeId;
    }
    public void setCollegeId(int collegeId) {
        this.collegeId = collegeId;
    }


}


@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private boolean bachelor;
    @ManyToOne
    private College college;

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public boolean isBachelor() {
        return bachelor;
    }
    public void setBachelor(boolean bachelor) {
        this.bachelor = bachelor;
    }
    public College getCollege() {
        return college;
    }
    public void setCollege(College college) {
        this.college = college;
    }
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

}
```

Here is i am trying to make one of the student association null with college but nothing is happening on flush/commit. I am not sure what is getting missed here?

```
    Session session1 = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx1 = session1.beginTransaction();
    College College1 = (College)session1.get(College.class, 1);
    List <Student> students = College1.getStudents();
    System.out.println("student size is " + students.size());
    students.remove(0);
    System.out.println("student size is " + College1.getStudents().size());
    session1.update(College1);

    session1.flush();
    tx1.commit();
    session1.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Student` is owning the relationship , you should set `student.college` as null and update

```
List <Student> students = College1.getStudents();
students.get(0).setCollege(null);
students.remove(0);
session1.update(students.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add orhpanRemoval flag to collection:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="college", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Student> students;
```

Second thing - you don't have to call:

```
session1.update(College1);
session1.flush();
```

College1 is already managed by entityManager so it will be synchronized with DB, flush() is unncessary here becase commit() force to flush by default.